Issue in orbit propagator with wmm2020 output
I am trying to build an orbit propagator with input of latitude and longitude in wmm2020 to plot the magnitude of the geomagnetic field.  The orbit seems good but the field plot is completely wrong.  Could someone please help me figure out the problem?
from skyfield.api import load, EarthSatellite, wgs84
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wmm2020
import numpy as np

# Carregar o modelo de tempo
ts = load.timescale()

# Definir os elementos de dois linhas (TLE) do ISS
line1 = '1 25544U 98067A  19343.69339541  .00001764  00000-0  38792-4 0  9991'
line2 = '2 25544  51.6439 211.2001 0007417  17.6667  85.6398 15.50103472202482'

# Criar um objeto EarthSatellite para o ISS
satellite = EarthSatellite(line1, line2, 'ISS (ZARYA)', ts)

# Definir o tempo inicial e final
t = ts.utc(2014, 1, 23, 1, 1, range(0, 60))

# Obter a posição do ISS no tempo especificado
geocentric = satellite.at(t)

altitude_km = geocentric.position.km[2]

# Obter latitude e longitude
lat, lon = wgs84.latlon_of(geocentric)

# Converter latitude e longitude para graus
lat_degrees = lat.degrees
lon_degrees = lon.degrees

time_seconds = np.arange(0, 60)

Bx, By, Bz = [], [], []

for i in range(len(lat_degrees)):
    mag = wmm2020.wmm(lat_degrees[i], lon_degrees[i], altitude_km[i], 2024.5)
    Bx.append(mag['north']) 
    By.append(mag['east'])
    Bz.append(mag['down'])

Bx = np.squeeze(Bx)
By = np.squeeze(By)
Bz = np.squeeze(Bz)

# Plotar os dados
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(lon_degrees, lat_degrees, 'b.')

plt.title('Trajetória da ISS (ZARYA)')
plt.xlabel('Longitude (graus)')
plt.ylabel('Latitude (graus)')
plt.grid(True)

# Plotar os dados em 3 subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10, 12))  # 3 linhas, 1 coluna

# Plotar Bx
axs[0].plot(time_seconds, Bx, 'r')
axs[0].set_title('Componente Bx do Campo Magnético')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Tempo (segundos)')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Bx (nT)')

# Plotar By
axs[1].plot(time_seconds, By, 'g')
axs[1].set_title('Componente By do Campo Magnético')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Tempo (segundos)')
axs[1].set_ylabel('By (nT)')

# Plotar Bz
axs[2].plot(time_seconds, Bz, 'b')
axs[2].set_title('Componente Bz do Campo Magnético')
axs[2].set_xlabel('Tempo (segundos)')
axs[2].set_ylabel('Bz (nT)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

